# Vue JS component doesn't show on index.blade Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My vue js component doesnt show on my project. I don't see any errors from my part as I have seen many examples before and this is the right logic to implement it. Can anyone help me?

index.blade.php file

```
<div id="app">
<div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3">
     <div class="h3">{{ $user->username}}</div>

     <follow-button></follow-button>
</div>
</div>
```

FollowButton.vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4"> Follow Me </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('follow-button', require('./components/FollowButton.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

ExampleComponent.vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ...`el: '#app',` where id `id="app"`

Comment: remove `default` from followbuton

Comment: add `<example-component/>` to index.blade.php

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor if I remove the word 'default' it gives me three errors bc it says export cannot be used without it... and I also tried to add <example-component/> to index and still doesnt show anything like <follow-button.,,,

Comment: you should include  `follow-button` into `example-componet`... and use it

Comment: `import FollowButton from './FollowButton'`  into example-componet

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor omg still doesnt work... i tried both ways

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor doesnt work ... i dont know man..

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor the only error that im getting now is: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ';' is not a valid attribute name. i dont even know what it is

Comment: are you looping something ?

Comment: @abdullah no. I just want this component to show on my page. Just a simple button or either a text wont compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same problem with me, somehow I had two divs with the same id="app" and that made sure that my vue.js file not to be implemented on my laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use `<div id="app">` inside write all vuejs code

### Add this in app.js

```js
Vue.component('follow-button', require('./components/FollowButton.vue').default);
```

after register `follow-button` you can use

```html
<div id="app">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3">
        <div class="h3">{{ $user->username}}</div>
        <follow-button> </follow-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### after that run `npm run dev`

> Note: - make sure `index.blade.php` here you added `app.js` file

Comment: I have tried this way and I don't know why I have posted it as 'example-component' on app.js file :P ... still doesnt work :/

Comment: I did it, I also tried doing npm run watch ... still nothing on the page :/

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> already it

Comment: i installed it and after i refresh my page, it says vue.js not detected

Comment: then check your `app.js` file is included or not

Comment: Note: - make sure `index.blade.php` here you added `app.js` file

Answer (score 0):

try to add to index.blade.php file

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```